# Is there a simple way for constructing an n by n array from two unequal arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays

```
X_1 = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
[ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
[0, 3, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 2],
[3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0]]

X_2 = [0,1,2,3]
```

I want to derive a 4 by 4 B array such that every `B[i,j]` element is the total number of values of `X_2[i]` in `X_1[j]`

Output:

```
B = [[0,16,3,2],
[0,0,21,2],
[7,2,6,7],
[3,3,4,14]]
```

Comment: What does "total number of values of X_2[i] in X_1[j]" mean? Please provide expected output. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: sum of all occurrences i.e number of 0's in X_1[0] at X_2[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try nested loops like

```
B = []
for i in X_1:
    counts = []
    for y in X_2:
        counts.append(i.count(y))
    B.append(counts)
print(B)
```

Output

```
[[0, 16, 3, 2], [0, 0, 21, 2], [7, 2, 6, 8], [3, 3, 4, 14]]
```

Comment: Thank you, it did what I just wanted with a few modifications. counts.append(np.count_nonzero(y==i))